# TeXMaker with MikTex on Arch?

Tags: miktex, texlive, texmaker, linux

Is it possible to run Texmaker with miktex instead of texlive on Arch Linux (like it does on Windows)? The AUR Texmaker package depends on texlive-core. I have tried compiling from source but it seems like Texmaker for Linux was intended to be run with texlive (unlike the Windows version).

Comment: I highly doubt that texmaker does anything but just call pdflatex so the latex dist does not matter. Does miktex even run on your system and is it correctly in your path?

Comment: Why not use texlive?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.

- Install `miktex` from the AUR
- Start the MiKTeX Console and click 'Finish private setup'
- You may need to add (for a private setup) `~/bin` to your PATH, and log out and back in, to make sure that `pdflatex` is found. For the admin setup, add `/usr/local/bin`.
- Start and use texmaker (or in fact any other LaTeX editor), worked fine for me.